# How to uninstall Cortana from my phone permanently - NOT just disable it

Tags: 8.1, cortana

I never want his "assistant"  interrupting my work again. I want it OFF my phone permanently. How do I uninstall it?

Answer (score 9):

As Cortana is not an app but a part of the system you can't uninstall her, just deactivate the service by going to settings -> applications -> Cortana.

Answer (score 8):

I don't know how Cortana is disturbing your work, but there is a feature in the system setting, which is supposed to not disturb the user when he doesn't want: Quiet Hours, you could even set some rules as to who could disturb you. For the Quiet Hours: in Settings > Quiet Hours

And as it was mentioned earlier, it is part of the system, you cannot uninstall it, only disable it.

You could also fine tune Cortana (her notebook in fact) to what information "she" can access.

Answer (score 1):

Some mobile device management (MDM) service providers, such as Miradore (which is free), allow you to set a policy to disable Cortana.

While Cortana cannot be removed from the phone, when it is disabled by policy, it will no longer be displayed in the application list.

(You can also use MDM policies to enable device encryption and to disable other features that are potentially privacy-unfriendly, such as Wi-Fi Sense and SQM data reporting.)

Answer (score -1):

frankly, reinstall the system to locality which does not support cortana might help, my phone is set to poland>>english (uk) and i dont have cortana-

this might require reboot though

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: im sorry but your comment seems off-topic?

Comment: This response is actually totally on topic, if a bit radical. The question wasn't about *disabling* Cortana, it was emphatically about *removing* it ("want it OFF my phone"). This method ensures that Cortana isn't reactivated by a Windows update unless/until Microsoft get it to work in English in Poland, which seems rather unlikely. In contrast, recent Windows updates keep silently re-installing and re-activating functionality that was removed or disabled for privacy reasons, basically making the use of Windows criminal for doctors, lawyers etc.